# Event when dismissing the entry without modifications?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I'm having an entry:

```
auto myEntry = elm_entry_add(..);
```

Its *focused* event works great for detecting when it's getting *actually* edited:

```
evas_object_smart_callback_add(myEntry, "focused", onOpen, NULL);
```

This calls my `onOpen` function when the entry is focused, thus when it's getting edited:

[image]

When I edit the text, I can use another event: *changed*, to detect when user finishes (or more appropriate: *changed,user*).

However, when user just dismiss it without changing (by pressing the back key), I don't get any events:

- aborted: not called
- changed: not called, as text has not been changed
- unfocused: not called, as the entry hasn't lost its focus, just it's editor has been closed.

Other events are mainly for selection and cursor.

**How can I detect when editor has been closed?**

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is best.

Note that there is also a way to use conformant's API.
https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/container-conformant/

```
evas_object_smart_callback_add(ad->conform, "virtualkeypad,size,changed", keypad_size_changed, NULL);
```

```
static void keypad_size_changed(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
{
    Eina_Rectangle *rect = event_info;
    printf("keypad_size_changed [%d %d %d %d] \n", rect->x, rect->y, rect->w, rect->h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not realized that `elm_entry` has a function for this:

```
Ecore_IMF_Context* imfctx = elm_entry_imf_context_get(myEntry);
ecore_imf_context_input_panel_event_callback_add(imfctx, ECORE_IMF_INPUT_PANEL_STATE_EVENT, on_input_panel_state_event, NULL);
```

This works just fine with the callback being:

```
void on_input_panel_state_event(void *data, Ecore_IMF_Context *ctx, int state)
```

`state` is a value from `Ecore_IMF_Input_Panel_State`, can be *SHOW*, *HIDE* or *WILL_SHOW*.